# Is block creation guaranteed to be running after parent block is fully imported?

Tags: consensus, block-production, inherent, block-import

I observe an issue for a long time that I can't explain.

There is a value produced in `BlockImport::import_block` that must be included in inherents of `n+1`.
Though sometimes it seems like value is not available yet.
I have checked the code multiple times over last months and can't find any issue with it.

This seems to be correlated with blocks produced locally by the `node`.
I'm wondering if it is possible that block `n` is built locally and block building starts for `n+1` (creating inherents, etc) before `n` goes through `BlockImport::import_block` successfully (it doesn't do full execution there because `block.state_action == StateAction::ApplyChanges`)?

Consensus is custom, but based on `sc-consensus-slots`.

Comment: But the state of `N` is already there? You are sure that you use the same block import pipeline for import and block production?

Comment: I mean we have a single block import pipeline in the blockchain through which every block goes sooner or later. For locally produced blocks the state is computed during block production, but whether it is already in the state tree (or whatever it is called) or not I'm not sure yet.

Comment: No I meant if you really start producing block `n + 1` or again `n` because the block import wasn't not yet finished?

Comment: `sc-consensus-slots` produces blocks in sequence, I suspect it never tries to produce a block before the previous one succeeds. But concurrent blocks can be created by other nodes on the network (and during last reproduction I observed heavy temporary forking).

Comment: Yeah, but you are saying that it starts building on n, without having finished import of n. Without the state of n you can not build n + 1.

Comment: Right, but state is known before block import if block is local. It is created in the process of block proposing if I understand it correctly. I don't know if it is available for future block production (this is essentially the question), but technically it is already known, hence `StateAction::ApplyChanges`.

Comment: The state is known to other components when it is imported by the DB, before this point you can not use the state anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental reason I asked the question was due to an edge-case I was hitting where inherents didn't have expected contents even though the process of creating data for inherents relied on blocks being imported sequentially.

Turned out `SimpleSlotWorker` imports blocks directly, so it is possible that something relatively long-running before block import exit can eventually return AFTER new block is imported on top of it.

Here is a more detailed description of what was happening: https://github.com/subspace/subspace/issues/871#issuecomment-1722745138

So the answer to original question is both Yes and No. No, technically block is indeed imported *before* next block is created, so it is not possible create an ancestor before tht. But also yes, it is certainly possible to create a block before corresponding outer `BlockImport::import_block` has actually returned, which is typically not an issue, but I was hitting exactly that case.